# What is the correct way to set up a virtual host running on Apache?

Tags: apache2, virtualhost

I configured apache on ubuntu 16.04 and I created a virtual host with these instructions:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
        Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html

        ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
        CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

when I try to open the page www.example.com on my browser I see this message:

```
This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.
```

Should I use another name instead of "example" to solve the problem?

Ok any name? For example "myname.com"

For clarity, I only need this for local tests

Answer (score 0):

www.example.com is actual website that somebody else owns, has it registered in DNS and has some content on it. When you open the address in browser, your computer first asks DNS server (presumably one setup by your ISP). DNS then responds, that www.example.com is ran on 93.184.216.34 - which is probably not your machine. This is where the message is from.

Now, what is the meaning of ServerName and ServerAlias then? It is actualy a directive for your webserver, running on your machine, to know which packets are meant for given virtual host. It does not affect how your browser will transalate them.

For the sake of local testing (both server and browser are on same OS), all you need to do is to create virtualhost for a 'localhost'. This is a reserved address for the machine currently being used. Simply put:

```
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
```

into your virtualhost and you will be able to access the webserver by entering 'localhost' into your browser.

In case you would need more than one host locally, you can override the dns by editing the host file https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) - for example, in windows by adding hosts records like:

```
    127.0.0.1 app.local
    127.0.0.1 db.local
```

and then creating two different virtual hosts, one with alias app.local, second with db.local. Then, the OS will then route requests from your browser correctly to your machine per hosts file. Your websever will then sort your request according to the header to proper virtualhost.

You might want to check out some general information on how dns and internet protocol works:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System